# Is it wise to read a single database resultset with multiple threads considering performance gain

Tags: database, multithreading, performance, oracle

I execute a query on an Oracle database with Java using a single connection. Would that be faster to use multiple threads rather than one to read from this single resultset ?

Consider i will implement threads safety of read operation myself.

Simply i wonder, is there any performance gain reading from a single resultset over a single connection with multiple threads ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question - but in modern hosting environments, network bandwidth is rarely a bottleneck...

Comment: Well if you do compare processing power with network bandwith, network is almost always a bottleneck, unless you have a very weak server/computer

Comment: @pilcrow, is it ok now ?

Answer (score 2):

> is there any performance gain reading from a single resultset over a single connection with multiple threads ?

If all those threads are doing is reading, then no. Multiple threads could even make it slower because you'll have to do some kind of synchronization to prevent concurrent reads. So your multiple threads end up executing sequentially. You might even find that a single connection can't be accessed by any thread other than the one that created it.

Now, if you want to read from one database and write to another, you're probably better off using some kind of producer-consumer relationship. The producer reads from the database and puts the data on a queue. The consumer thread reads from the queue and writes to the other database.

So the producer does this:

```
while not end of data
    read record
    put record on input queue
end-while
mark end of queue
```

The consumer:

```
while not end of queue
    remove item from input queue
    write record to database
end-while
```

With that configuration, you get a very large performance gain because the threads operate independently of each other, except for that shared queue which is typically a data structure that's optimized for concurrent access in this manner. .NET, for example, has the `BlockingCollection` for this. Other environments likely have something quite similar.

Comment: Well, let's say i used a producer consumer pattern here, still, would that be better using multiple threads read and put to the queue from a single resultset and multiple consumer threads write them concurrently ?

Comment: What environment and what language/platform are you talking about? In Java, for example, a database connection and all associated objects are not thread safe. The same is true for .NET.

Comment: @Olaf Does that make any difference with changing platform and languages ? I assumed there is no thread safety, i will have to implement thread safety surely , edited my question accordingly

Comment: @Olaf: Which is why I said that you'd have to add synchronization to prevent concurrent reads. I also mentioned that it might not even be possible to access the same connection from multiple threads.

Comment: @gomyes: My point is that if you are planning to read a resultset in a normal 3G language environment, reading it in a single thread using a producer/consumer model is your best option. If you are talking about a PL/SQL stored procedure, there might be even better options, but you should tag your question correspondngly to make it visible to PL/SQL experts on SO.

Comment: @Olaf Oh, you are right, actually i had Java, .NET like high level database independent languages. Will edit my question accordingly

Comment: @gomyes: I don't think it's useful (might not even be possible) to have multiple threads reading the same result set. Same for the update. Use *one thread* for reading the data. Use *one thread* to write the data. If you need to do some processing in the middle, have multiple threads do the processing and write to a shared queue that the *one output thread* reads and writes to the database.